# How do I run MyLocationDemoActivity.java?

Tags: android-studio

How do I run MyLocationDemoActivity.java? I got this file from GitHub this is the link:
https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/tree/master

I am completely new to Android Studio, what are the steps to run this file?

On the getting started subtitle when you scroll down on the GitHub site, it tells says to create a file on the "root directory" called secure. properties. I am sorry, but I have no clue what or where the root directory is located and how to create the file. But I did get an Google Maps API key.

I also did import the project, but how do I add an emulator. I have downloaded the emulator and it works because on a different project I created a Google Maps Activity Project and just ran the sample code putting a marker on Sydney. I am not sure how to add the emulator to the project I downloaded from github though. I tried to add a template configuration for an android app, but it says no module. How do I add that?  In summary, I am just looking for a step by step way to run this file.
(Also, I am sorry if this seems like a mess of questions, but I really have no idea what I am doing)

[image: stuck on adding configurations]

[image: module problem]

Answer (score 0):

You question sounds too generic, so I will give some suggestions:

1. `demo activity` could not be run separately, you have to create a full environment of android and open the `main activity`, then open this `demo activity`
2. Don't use emulator for developing Map features, use a real device. In fact, I always use "Real Device" when developing, because "emulator" seems lots of bug, and its speed is very slow.
3. when studying a new tech/skill/feature, bit by bit. e.g.
   3.1 you should know some knowlege about android main activity, android basics
   3.2 play with emulator and real device, and know adb commands
   3.2 play with DemoActivity

good luck!